# Is there a formular, to detect the direction a square is facing, given all 4 points of the square?

Tags: vector, orientation, perspective, normals, plane

[Here is a drawing of the concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5xjk.jpg). My smalish QR script gives me the 4 points of the (perspectivly skewed) rectangle. I now all points and therefore all angles. I can determine the center by some basic geometry, but I dont get how I could calculate the vector of the direction the rect/plane is facing (red line in the diagramm). I'm looking to achieve some kind of minimal AR effect.

Thank you.